# When we cannot type in a petalinux login prompt?

Tags: linux, boot, petalinux

Not sure if it is a valid question. I had a working petalinux system in my zynq 7000 board. After software update of my main machine or (something else) and power cycle my board, I cannot type anything in the login prompt. Internet search did not give much hint as it seems to be happen rarely. Are there few possible reason or uncountable number of reason which would lead to such behaviour?

EDIT: Tried to see if the USB is workinf fine or not?

```
$ dmesg | grep -i 210x
```

I get the following:

```
[168268.628647] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 17
[168268.628753] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed get req 0x14 size 16 status: -19
[168268.628763] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x12 status: -19
[168268.628767] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x0 status: -19
```

I used 210x in my grep command as `lsusb` gives my device name as:

```
BUS 001 Device 018: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
```

What does the failed status mean? Does this error messages related to the problem or not?